# Unable to remove DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

The picture above is what I'm working on. When any of the empty square is clicked on, it should append the value to  `$("#captureAvail")` and  `$("#captureAvail2")`.At the same time it must a class that makes the square green in colour. That class is called 'green2'. Now I'm unable to successfully remove the element when the item clicked again or when the 'green2' class is removed. Just help me with that please. Below is my code. When I added this line: `$("#captureAvail").remove("<input type='hidden' name='avail[]' value='"+thisValue+"'>");`, I found the the squares became unclickable .Below is my script for it.

```
$("#greeny td:not(:first-child)").on("click",function()//prevent the first column to be clickable
       {
          //alert($(this).text());
           var thisValue = $(this).text();
           //
           if($(this).hasClass('green2'))
           {
               $(this).removeClass('green2');
                $("#captureAvail").remove("<input type='hidden' name='avail[]' value='"+thisValue+"'>");
                $("#captureAvail2").remove("<input type='hidden' name='avail[]' value='"+thisValue+"'>");
           }else
           {
               $(this).addClass('green2');
                $("#captureAvail").append("<input type='hidden' name='avail[]' value='"+thisValue+"'>");
                $("#captureAvail2").append("<input type='hidden' name='avail[]' value='"+thisValue+"'>");
           }

           //$(this).toggleClass("green2");
           //

           //$("#captureAvail").css("background-color","#ff0000");
       });
```

Comment: the `remove` function does not do what you think it does...

Comment: See also http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `remove()` method does not work as you are using it. It takes a selector as a parameter, not a HTML string, although you don't need that in your case. Try this:

```
$("#captureAvail").find('[value="' + thisValue + '"]').remove();
$("#captureAvail2").find('[value="' + thisValue + '"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 4):

The `remove` function removes the elements matched in the jquery selector. You need to remove its *children* instead:

```
$("#captureAvail").empty();
```

Comment: won't this remove all items in the #captureAvail ? I only want the particular square to be removed?

Comment: Note that this will remove all `input` elements from that container. If the UI needs to toggle only certain elements on/off this may not work correctly.

Comment: Yes, that is true, if this is not what you are looking for, then you can specify a better selector and use `remove`, or use `find` as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand remove function of jQuery.

https://api.jquery.com/remove/

So becomes below:

```
$("#captureAvail input").remove('[value=' + thisValues + ']');
$("#captureAvail2 input").remove('[value=' + thisValues + ']');
```